# Pass a message to facebook from a html/JS/CSS app

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am using the facebook "sharer" url from my web app, but the message part stays empty and  I would like to automatically pre-fill it with some text.

```
window.location='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]='+encodeURIComponent('myapp') + '&p[summary]=' + encodeURIComponent(text) + '&p[url]=' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '&p[images][0]=' + encodeURIComponent('http://www.somedomain.com/image.jpg')
```

How can I do this with a simple jquery function ?
Or maybe there is another solution than "sharer.php" for the user of my app to post on his wall directly from a button in my app ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a lot of reading, but the Facebook JavaScript SDK will provide what you need. As for publishing comments, see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/#comments

Comment: I realise that maybe what I mean instead of "comment" is a "message" associated to the shared link...sorry

Comment: can you provide a snippet to do this in jquery ?

Comment: There isn't any way to pass a message to sharer.php anymore. You would have to use the following: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/#publish Also see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/ to log the user in and to set the correct permissions. It's not as simple as a code snippet I'm afraid!